# Converting from string to lambda

Tags: javascript, java, lambda, scriptengine

I'm trying to use ScriptEngine to convert from a string to a lambda function for input. This is what I've come up so far, but I only experience errors:

```
ScripEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
someFunctionThatTakesInALambdaEquation((Function<Double, Double>)engine.eval("x -> x + 3"));
```

Comment: You might add the `javascript` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's syntax for a lambda expression is `x => x + 3`, or equivalently you can write it as an anonymous function `function(x) { return x + 3; }`.
Take note that it is slightly different from Java's syntax for a lambda expression `x -> x + 3`.

So I tried `engine.eval("x => x + 3");`, but got an exception from the script engine. I don't understand why.
But with

```
AbstractJSObject obj = (AbstractJSObject) engine.eval("function(x) { return x + 3; }");
```

you can get a JavaScript function object. Then you need to convert this to a Java function object (aka lambda expression).

```
Function<Double, Double> f = x -> (Double) obj.call(null, x);
```

and then do what ever you like

```
someFunctionThatTakesInALambdaExpression(f);
```

Comment: This works just fine. The "x => x + 3" syntax doesn't work for me either. Not sure why...

Comment: "x => x + 3" seems to work fine. y=eval("x => x + 3"); y(3); // prints out 6